# When is a proper morphism of varieties a closed immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is anyone aware of a criterion for when a proper morphism of varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ being injective on points implies that it is an immersion? More precisely, suppose we have $f:X\to Y$ a morphism of varieties over an algebraically closed field $k=\overline{k}$. In my situation, what I have is that for any algebra $A$ over $k$, the map $X(A) \to Y(A)$ is injective. Does this imply that the map $f$ is a closed immersion?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV

Comment: @AlexYoucis could you explain why the map $X(A)\to Y(A)$ injective for all $A$ suffices? I don't see a direct translation of that condition in the link. If it's the same as universally injective, don't you need unramified as well? Or does that condition somehow already capture the unramified hypothesis? (Sorry if this seems a bit quick/eager, I've been trying to write a solution using that but I couldn't quite make it fit.)

Comment: @KReiser I'm sorry -- doesn't that imply that $X\to Y$ is a monomorphism?

Comment: Thanks, that works for me!

Comment: @KReiser Upon rereading my comment, it sounds quite obnoxious. I meant it to sound like "Am I making a mistake?" but it doesn't read as such. I apologize.

Comment: @AlexYoucis hey, thanks for clarifying, I've found myself in a similar spot once or twice so I get it. Is it clear that the listed condition is equivalent to a monomorphism? (I haven't had cause to work with the functor of points approach much, so apologies if I'm missing an obvious solution.)

Comment: @KReiser Take a look at my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just spell out my above comment in more detail. By [Tag 04XV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV) it suffices to clarify why your assumption that $X(A)\to Y(A)$ is an injection for all $k$-algebras implies that $X\to Y$ is a monomorphism.

---

Let us fix a base scheme $S$ and two $S$-schemes $X$ and $Y$.

> **Definition:** A morphism of $S$-schemes $f\colon X\to Y$ is called a *monomorphism* if for any $S$-scheme $Z$ and maps $a,b\colon Z\to X$ the equality $f\circ a=f\circ b$ implies that $a=b$.

Note this is equivalent to the diagonal map $\Delta_f\colon X\to X\times_Y X$ being an isomorphism in the category of $S$-schemes. This observation indicates that the base $S$ plays no real role here : no part of the diagonal map depends on $S$, nor does it being an isomorphism. So, while the Stacks Project reference takes $S=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ (i.e. has no base), your conditions make it convenient to work with $S=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$.

So, let us show that the conditions you stated imply that $f\colon X\to Y$ is a monomorphism of $k$-schemes.

> **Proposition:** Let $S$ be a scheme. Then, the functor $\mathbf{Sch}_S\to \mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ given by $X\mapsto h_X$ is faithful.${}^{\color{red}{(1)}}$

Here

- $\mathbf{Sch}_S$ is the category of all $S$-schemes,
- $\mathbf{Aff}_S$ the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Sch}_S$ consisting of affine $S$-schemes (affine in the sense that they are actually affine, not the map to $S$ is affine)
- $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ is the category of presheaves on $\mathbf{Aff}_S$,
- $h_X$ is the representable presheaf $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sch}_S}(-,X)$ on $\mathbf{Aff}_S$.

*Proof:* By Yoneda's lemma we know that $h_\bullet$ fully faithfully embeds $\mathbf{Sch}_S$ into $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Sch}_S)$. So, it suffices to show that the restriction functor $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Sch}_S)\to\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ is faithful. This amounts to the claim that if $X_1(A)\to X_2(A)$ is injective for all $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to S$ in $\mathbf{Sch}_S$ then $X_1(T)\to X_2(T)$ is injective for any $T\to S$ in $\mathbf{Sch}_T$. But, recall that every $S$-scheme admits a canonical decomposition into a colimit of its affine open subschemes (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250068/is-it-always-possible-to-write-a-scheme-as-a-colimit-of-affine-schemes)). So, if we write $T=\mathrm{colim}\,\, \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ then it's not hard to see that $X_1(T)\to X_2(T)$ is $\lim\,\, (X_1(A)\to X_2(A))$. As the limit of injections is an injection, we're done. $\blacksquare$

Why is this useful? Well, it's trivial to see that if $F\colon \mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a faithful functor then $F(f)$ is a monomorphism implies that $f$ is a monomorphism : if $F(f\circ a)=F(f\circ b)$ then $F(f)\circ F(a)=F(f)\circ F(b)$ so $F(a)=F(b)$ and so $a=b$. Applying this for $h_{\bullet}\colon \mathbf{Sch}_S\to\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ shows that if $h_X\to h_Y$ is a monomorphism on $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ then $X\to Y$ is a monomorphism. But, $h_X\to h_Y$ being injective as a map on $\mathbf{PSh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ is precisely the statement that $X(A)\to Y(A)$ is injective for all objects $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to S$ of $\mathbf{Aff}_S$.

$\color{red}{(1)}$ : In fact, the representable presheaf actually defines a *fully faithful* embedding into $\mathbf{Psh}(\mathbf{Aff}_S)$ which actually factorizes through the category of sheaves over many Grothendieck topologies on $\mathbf{Aff}_S$. A good reference for this is [Olsson, §1.4].

**References:**

[Olsson] Olsson, M., 2016. Algebraic spaces and stacks (Vol. 62). American Mathematical Soc..

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.